# Zigbee firmware for CC2530 chips

Tags: zigbee, texas-instruments, firmware

If I buy a transceiver module with CC2530 like [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/CC2530-CC2530F256-Wireless-Module-Communication-Module-2-4G-In-Zigbee-RF4CE-/331413245591?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4d29c4ce97) and a programmer for it like [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Zigbee-Emulator-Debugger-Programmer-Support-CC1110-CC2430-CC2530-CC2540-CC2531-/281595162918?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_77&hash=item4190613126) is there any readily available firmware for the chip or will I have to write the firmware myself?
If available is it free or do I have to buy it from TI or a 3rd party?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is FW available for free. You should download TI's zstack-home from here:
http://www.ti.com/tool/z-stack

you the have a few options:

1. Use IAR (this will meaning buying a license) to write a ZigBee application on the CC2530. Example Applications for the following are supplied in zstack-home SDK:

   - Light: A light that can be turned on/off locally or remotely.
   - Switch: A switch that acts as a remote to turn a light on/off .
   - DoorLock: A door lock that can be locked/unlocked locally or remotely with ability to change master PIN.
   - DoorLockController: A controller that locks/unlocks the door lock device based on user PIN input.
   - TemperatureSensor: Sends current temperature reading to the thermostat.
   - Thermostat: A unit that receives temperature information from the Temperature Sensor and adjusts the room temperature by sending heating/cooling commands to the Heating/Cooling Unit.
   - HeatingCoolingUnit: A unit that heats or cools based on the received information from the thermostat.
2. Load the pre-built network procesor FW (no need for IAR), provided in \Projects\zstack\ZAP\ZNP-HexFiles (described in Z-Stack Home 1.2.1\Documents\API\CC2530\CC2530ZNP Interface Specification.pdf). Then connect a host MCU to the UART of the CC2530 and use the open source "Host Sw Framework" available at https://git.ti.com/znp-host-framework/znp-host-framework to control the CC2530 Netork processor.

Regards,
TC.